# How can I create a canvas in Swift that I can move and place some components on?

Tags: swift, ipad, swiftui, sprite-kit, uikit

I want to create an app for my iPad to design some simple electronic schematics using SwiftUI. But I don't know the best way to create the canvas - the workspace - for my app. I would like to move it vertically and horizontally. And I would also like to zoom, like in a map app.

I have no idea which framework I should use.
I thought of SpriteKit because it's a 2D framework designed for games, but I'm not sure if there is a better solution.

Which of the frameworks in Swift could handle this?

- SwiftUI
- UIKit
- SpriteKit?
- Something else I've never heard of?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: you can use SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like a SpriteKit approach would work.

Using `SKCamera` will allow you to scroll around and zoom in/out of an `SKScene`.

`SKScene` has a bunch of built in methods for responding to clicks/taps on specific areas of the view.